# In how many ways can we distribute tickets?

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

> We have $100$ indistinguishable tickets and $40$ children. In how many ways can we distribute tickets if each child is to receive at least one ticket and not all tickets have to be distributed?

Below is a solution which I am not sure is correct and would like someone to check it:

1. We give each child $1$ ticket. We do it the $1$ way because the tickets are indistinguishable.
2. We have $60$ tickets left. Let $x_i$ - the number of additional tickets (from the remaining $60$) that the $i$-th child will receive. Then we have the inequality to solve:
   $$x_1+x_2+\dots+x_{40}\le 60; x_i\ge 0$$
   The number of solutions to this inequality is the same as the number of solutions to the equation: $$x_1+x_2+\dots+x_{40}+y= 60; x_i\ge 0,y\ge0$$
   (in our problem, $y$ is the number of tickets that we did not give to the children)
   We solve the above equation using the method stars and bars: we have $60$ stars which we want to separate with $40$ balls (because we have 41 "shelves" - forty $x_i$ and one $y$), so the solution is: $$\binom{60+40}{60}=\binom{100}{60}$$

Comment: Your solution looks fine.

Comment: seems right to me

Comment: Just a question if it has said that not all the tickets have to distributed then the why do we have a case of  equality in $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 .... \le 60$

Comment: @SisantaChhatoi Because it doesn't prohibit the distribution of all the tickets. It's just not compulsory that we distribute them all.

Comment: @Haris got it thx